# How to pass variable in JSON dot noration?

Tags: javascript, json, api, postman

I am using cryptocompare API to convert the currency to EUR in **POSTMAN**, I have json data having 128 countries currency. I want to convert any currency to **EUR** and get PRICE when user enter the currency in fsyms (from symbol), it can convert it into EUR. When I read the fsyms that user can enter, I store this value in a variable called userinput, the issue is when I pass this variable between **jsonData.DISPLAY.userinput.EUR.PRICE** it cannot be work and show error in postman console **TypeError: Cannot read property 'EUR' of undefined**.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mamF.png)

[POSTMAN TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VznXF.png)

**API**

```
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=JPY&tsyms=EUR
```

**POSTMAN TEST**

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
const paramsString = request.url.split('?')[1];
const eachParamArray = paramsString.split('&');
let params = {};
eachParamArray.forEach((param) => {
    const key = param.split('=')[0];
    const value = param.split('=')[1];
    Object.assign(params, {[key]: value});
});
var userinput = (params.fsyms);// this is object with request params as key value pairs
var data = jsonData.DISPLAY.userinput.EUR.PRICE;
console.log(userinput);
```

**Body**

```
{
    "RAW": {
        "JPY": {
            "EUR": {
                "TYPE": "5",
                "MARKET": "CCCAGG",
                "FROMSYMBOL": "JPY",
                "TOSYMBOL": "EUR",
                "FLAGS": "1026",
                "PRICE": 0.008286298820795936,
                "LASTUPDATE": 1573165368,
                "MEDIAN": 0.008295432268182709,
                "LASTVOLUME": 204.04,
                "LASTVOLUMETO": 1.690736411395203,
                "LASTTRADEID": "1392678441",
                "VOLUMEDAY": 204327208.38121647,
                "VOLUMEDAYTO": 1693116.3058658,
                "VOLUME24HOUR": 220262096.6747532,
                "VOLUME24HOURTO": 1825157.551942048,
                "OPENDAY": 0.00813131941538667,
                "HIGHDAY": 0.008388929943067683,
                "LOWDAY": 0.008098208117154651,
                "OPEN24HOUR": 0.00815626332693239,
                "HIGH24HOUR": 0.008398161990353476,
                "LOW24HOUR": 0.008101851851851851,
                "LASTMARKET": "bitFlyer",
                "VOLUMEHOUR": 1385871.6724710271,
                "VOLUMEHOURTO": 11483.74680537116,
                "OPENHOUR": 0.008300374904680056,
                "HIGHHOUR": 0.00830320074996652,
                "LOWHOUR": 0.008280400605840016,
                "TOPTIERVOLUME24HOUR": 220262096.6747532,
                "TOPTIERVOLUME24HOURTO": 1825157.551942048,
                "CHANGE24HOUR": 0.0001300354938635461,
                "CHANGEPCT24HOUR": 1.5943023005910366,
                "CHANGEDAY": 0.00015497940540926645,
                "CHANGEPCTDAY": 1.9059564320644353,
                "CHANGEHOUR": -0.000014076083884120155,
                "CHANGEPCTHOUR": -0.1695837121306839,
                "SUPPLY": 0,
                "MKTCAP": 0,
                "TOTALVOLUME24H": null,
                "TOTALVOLUME24HTO": null,
                "TOTALTOPTIERVOLUME24H": 0,
                "TOTALTOPTIERVOLUME24HTO": 2.3283064365386963e-10,
                "IMAGEURL": "/media/35309345/no-image.png",
                "CONVERSIONTYPE": "invert_divide",
                "CONVERSIONSYMBOL": "ETH"
            }
        }
    },
    "DISPLAY": {
        "JPY": {
            "EUR": {
                "FROMSYMBOL": "¥",
                "TOSYMBOL": "€",
                "MARKET": "CryptoCompare Index",
                "PRICE": "€ 0.008286",
                "LASTUPDATE": "Just now",
                "MEDIAN": "€ 0.008295",
                "LASTVOLUME": "¥ 204.04",
                "LASTVOLUMETO": "€ 1.69",
                "LASTTRADEID": "1392678441",
                "VOLUMEDAY": "¥ 204,327,208.4",
                "VOLUMEDAYTO": "€ 1,693,116.3",
                "VOLUME24HOUR": "¥ 220,262,096.7",
                "VOLUME24HOURTO": "€ 1,825,157.6",
                "OPENDAY": "€ 0.008131",
                "HIGHDAY": "€ 0.008389",
                "LOWDAY": "€ 0.008098",
                "OPEN24HOUR": "€ 0.008156",
                "HIGH24HOUR": "€ 0.008398",
                "LOW24HOUR": "€ 0.008102",
                "LASTMARKET": "bitFlyer",
                "VOLUMEHOUR": "¥ 1,385,871.7",
                "VOLUMEHOURTO": "€ 11,483.7",
                "OPENHOUR": "€ 0.008300",
                "HIGHHOUR": "€ 0.008303",
                "LOWHOUR": "€ 0.008280",
                "TOPTIERVOLUME24HOUR": "¥ 220,262,096.7",
                "TOPTIERVOLUME24HOURTO": "€ 1,825,157.6",
                "CHANGE24HOUR": "€ 0.00013",
                "CHANGEPCT24HOUR": "1.59",
                "CHANGEDAY": "€ 0.00015",
                "CHANGEPCTDAY": "1.91",
                "CHANGEHOUR": "€ -0.000014",
                "CHANGEPCTHOUR": "-0.17",
                "SUPPLY": "¥ 0",
                "MKTCAP": "€ 0",
                "TOTALVOLUME24H": "¥ NaN",
                "TOTALVOLUME24HTO": "€ NaN",
                "TOTALTOPTIERVOLUME24H": "¥ 0",
                "TOTALTOPTIERVOLUME24HTO": "€ 2.328e-10",
                "IMAGEURL": "/media/35309345/no-image.png",
                "CONVERSIONTYPE": "invert_divide",
                "CONVERSIONSYMBOL": "ETH"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you're asking but try `jsonData.DISPLAY[userinput].EUR.PRICE`

Comment: @Phil It can show ReferenceError: userInput is not defined

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant `[userinput]` but can you see what it's trying to do anyway?

Comment: @Phil Read my question again i modify it.